# Как сделать что бы php воспринимал <style>

Tags: php, sql, style

Как сделать что бы php воспринимал стиль

Вот участок php кода который с бд вытаскивает значение столбца

```
<?php
                    $db = new mysqli("localhost","root","root","bez");
                    $db->set_charset("utf8");
                    $sql = $db->query ("SELECT * FROM klient");
                    $_r = $sql->num_rows;
                    if ($_r > 0)

                    {
                        while ($tablerows = $sql->fetch_array())
                        {
                            echo '




                                        <li id="menu-item-53" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-53">
                                        <a target="_blank" href="/" class="menu-image-title-before menu-image-not-hovered">
                                        <span class="menu-image-title">'.$tablerows[Name].'</span>

                            
                            ';
                            
                            
                        }                       
                        
                    }else{
                        echo '<tr><td colspan=4 style="text-align: center;">Ничего нет</td></tr>';
                    }

?>
```

Мне надо что бы вот эта часть

```
                                <li id="menu-item-53" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-53">
                                <a target="_blank" href="/" class="menu-image-title-before menu-image-not-hovered">
                                <span class="menu-image-title">'.$tablerows[Name].'</span>
```

Воспользовался вот этим стилем

```
<style>.navi_buttons ul {
    clear: both;
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    margin-right: -30px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.blue_buttons ul li,
.navi_buttons ul li {
    width: 80%;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    font-size: 1.125em;
    line-height: 1.1;
    text-align: center;
}

.blue_buttons ul li a span > span,
.navi_buttons ul li a span > span {
    display: block;
    text-transform: none;
    font-size: 0.778em;
    margin-top: 3px;
 }
.navi_buttons ul li {
    text-align: center;
    background: #2f3f5f;
}

.navi_buttons ul li:hover {
    background: #636f87;
}

.navi_buttons ul li a {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.navi_buttons ul li a:hover,
.navi_buttons ul li a:focus {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navi_buttons ul li a > span {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(0%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(0%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(0%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(0%);
    transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(0%);
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
}

.navi_buttons ul li a > img {
    max-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    float: right;
}
    </style>
```

Comment: РНР не имеет отношения к стилям. Чтобы HTML видел стили, их надо подключить

Comment: Выведите и стили и список